# BodyPix (Tensorflow.js) error: Unknown input type: [object ImageData]

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, bodypix

I am trying to load images serverside (locally) using node.js so that I can run the segmentation functions on them.

In the BodyPix README it states that the segmentPerson function accepts ImageData object images:
"Params in segmentPerson()
image - ImageData|HTMLImageElement|HTMLCanvasElement|HTMLVideoElement The input image to feed through the network."
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix

Here is my code:

```
var bodyPix = require("@tensorflow-models/body-pix");
var tfjs = require("@tensorflow/tfjs")
var inkjet = require('inkjet');
var createCanvas = require('canvas');
var fs = require('fs');

async function loadAndPredict(data) {
        const net = await bodyPix.load({
            architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
            outputStride: 16,
            multiplier: 0.75,
            quantBytes: 2
    });

    imgD = createCanvas.createImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(data.data), data.width, data.height);
    const segmentation = await net.segmentPerson(imgD, {
    flipHorizontal: false,
    internalResolution: 'medium',
    segmentationThreshold: 0.7
    });
    const maskImage = bodyPix.toMask(segmentation, false);
}

inkjet.decode(fs.readFileSync('./person.jpg'), function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('OK: Image');
    loadAndPredict(data)
  });
```

It loads an image from my current directory, then converts it to the specified ImageData format, then it feeds it into the segmentPerson function. The half of the code that doesn't relate to the loading and formatting of the image is stripped from the GitHub README AND has worked for me when using HTML Image elements.

However it returns an Unknown input type: [object ImageData] on the call to "net.segmentPerson(imgD,..."

I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue so any help or guidance would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this repo: https://github.com/ajaichemmanam/Posenet-NodeServer

Posenet (Bodypix uses this) is used in a nodejs server script. You can check how the image is loaded here and is used for posenet estimation